# ¿Mostrar registros de una tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en `MySQL`

[image: Tabla Pacientes]

Con los siguientes registros

```sql
insert into pacientes (PacIdentificacion, PacNombres, PacApellidos, PacFechaNacimiento, PacSexo)
                values ('1','KAREN IVETTE','MORALES YARURO','2000-09-05','F'),
                       ('2','LUISA FERNANDA','ROMERO TAPIA','1995-09-06','F'),
                       ('3','ALEXANDER','SANCHEZ TORRES','1998-03-15','M'),
                       ('4','MIGUEL ANGEL','CASTAÑEDA QUICENO','2001-09-08','M'),
                       ('5','TANIA MARCELA','ARIZA MOSQUERA','2000-02-23','F');
```

Y una segunda tabla, esta vez con los tratamientos de los pacientes

[image: Tabla tratamientos]

Con los siguientes registros

```sql
insert into tratamientos (tranumero, tradescripcion, trafechainicio, trafechafin, traobservaciones, trapacientes)
                    values (1,'Blanqueamiento Dental','2018-09-01','2019-10-01','','77191950'),
                           (2,'Ortodoncia','2019-05-10','2019-09-16','','77191950'),
                           (3,'Protesis Dental','2019-08-15','2019-09-20','','77191950'),
                           (4,'Implante Dental','2019-09-24','2019-11-07','','77191950'),
                           (5,'Diseño Sonrisa','2019-09-12','2019-10-13','','77191950');
```

Y tengo un ejercicio en el que me dice... 
**5.    Mostrar el nombre del paciente y su tratamiento si el nombre del tratamiento contiene la palabra “dental”.**

Actualmente resultaron dos posible sentencias para remediarlo, una es con subconsulta y la otra es directa.

Con Subconsulta:

```sql
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
           pacidentificacion in (select trapacientes from
           tratamientos where tradescripcion like '% dental');
```

Resultados:
[image: Resultado Subconsulta]

Directa:

```sql
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
        pacidentificacion = trapacientes and tradescripcion like '%Dental';
```

Resultados:
[image: Resultado de Consulta Directa]

En teoría a mi lógica ambas deberían poder mostrar los mismos resultados pero no es así, en la consulta directa se pierden 2 registros que perfectamente cumplen con la condición.
Aclaro que primeramente tenía la primera consulta pero se me ocurrio que podia hacerla mas corta pero no se que se me está pasando por alto que no funciona.

**¿Quien puede ayudarme con esta consulta para hacerla más corta o al menos explicarme qué está pasando con la consulta directa y no me muestra todos mis registros?**

(Aprovecho para indicar que el campo `TRAPACIENTES` es foráneo de `PACIDENTIFICACION`)

Comment: Realmente no es que se pierdan valores es que la primera consulta (con subconsulta es erronea) los 2 valores que no te aparecen en la segunda no deberían aparecer en la primera consulta.

Comment: Son consultas diferentes. No estás haciendo lo mismo

Comment: Cual es la relación foránea entre las dos tablas? creo que se te olvido colocar los vínculos , colócalos para poder ayudarte. VEO QUE ESTAN MAL EXPRESADOS

Comment: Tus datos de prueba, además, están mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si analizamos la primer consulta

```
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
       pacidentificacion in (select trapacientes from
       tratamientos where tradescripcion like '% dental');
```

Podemos ver que:

1. **No hay un `JOIN` implícito** entre los registros de las tablas `pacientes` y `tratamientos`, **lo que resulta en un producto cartesiano entre todos los registros que hay en ambas tablas**

   En otras palabras todos los `pacientes` repetidos tantas veces como `tratamientos` existan.
2. Al filtrar los `pacientes` cuyo `pacidentificacion` tengan un tratamiento donde la descripción contenga `% dental`, **solo afectas a los resultados de dicha tabla**, pero los pacientes resultantes se verá tantas veces como `tratamientos` existan en la tabla.
3. Si prestas atención, podemos ver que un resultado es `Ortodoncia` la cual no contiene `dental` y esto se debe a lo mencionado en el punto anterior.

---

Si analizamos la segunda consulta:

```
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
    pacidentificacion = trapacientes and tradescripcion like '%Dental';
```

Podemos ver que:

1. **Si hay un `JOIN` implícito** entre los registros de las tablas (`eg: pacidentificacion = trapacientes`), lo que indica que los registros ahora están relacionados entre sí.

   En otras, obtendrás **todos pacientes** y:

   - Los que no tengan `tratamientos` tendrán datos de está tabla pero igual a `NULL` (*efecto `LEFT JOIN`*).
   - Los que sí tengan `tratamientos` se repetirán tantas veces como registros asociados a estos existan en dicha tabla.
2. Luego al filtrar los registros cuyo `tradescripcion` contenga `dental`, obtendrás exactamente lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Me ha sucedido lo que dices en tu primer punto pero no entendí el porque de repetirse, podrías explicarmelo mejor o indicarme algún sitio donde lo pueda leer o vídeo también.

Comment: @MaxJimenez, puede que [este artículo](http://deletesql.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=18) te ayude a entender mejor el **producto cartesiano en `SQL`**.

Answer (score 1):

Primero: la relación entre pacidentificación y trapacientes que indicas no entrega nada con tus datos de ejemplo. En pacientes son 1,2,3,4,5 y en tratamientos son números de identificación. Tu ejemplo no es verificable.

Son consultas diferentes y no estás revisando qué es lo que entrega cada una, incluyendo la subconsulta.

En el primer caso

```
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
           pacidentificacion in (select trapacientes from
           tratamientos where tradescripcion like '% dental');
```

Estás buscando en `tratamientos`, identificas los pacientes que han tenido algún tratamiento cuyo nombre incluya `' dental'`, obtienes su identificación y la comparas con la columna `pacidentificación` de `pacientes` y luego omites hacer cualquier tipo de JOIN entre pacientes y tratamientos. Si la memoria no me falla, el motor ahí hace un NATURAL JOIN entre las dos y te muestra las combinaciones posibles. Sólo filtras la tabla `pacientes` usando la subconsulta.

En el segundo caso

```
select pacnombres, tradescripcion from pacientes, tratamientos where 
        pacidentificacion = trapacientes and tradescripcion like '%Dental';
```

Haces el JOIN implícito al indicar la relación entre los campos `pacidewntificacion` y `trapacientes` de pacientes y tratamientos, respectivamente (tienes un resultSet con los registros de `pacientes` y su registro correspondiente en `tratamientos`). Sobre ese conjunto, el motor filtra los que tienen 'Dental' en la descripción. No excluye datos nulos ni casos en los que un paciente no tenga tratamientos.

Dicho esto, qué quieres mostrar? Toda consulta es correcta dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer :) Por ejemplo, podrías usar un INNER JOIN (para evitar registros de `pacientes` con datos NULL si es que el paciente no ha tenido tratamientos) y ahí, filtrar la descripción del tratamiento que buscas. De paso, revisa que la búsqueda sea o no case-sensitive, porque ahí también difieren tus ejemplos.

Comment: @solamente, ahí esta la respuesta clara a una problemática bien explicada.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de realizar la consulta debería ser utilizando una INNER JOIN para comparar las dos tablas:

```
SELECT pacnombres, tradescripcion 
FROM pacientes p 
INNER JOIN tratamientos t
   ON t.trapacientes  = p.pacidentificacion 
WHERE tradescripcion like '%Dental%'
```

Comment: Agregaría a la respuesta que: se usa `INNERJOIN` para obtener los resultados que están vinculados en ambas tablas excluyendo aquellos que no

Comment: Hola solamente, el codigo me mostro los mismos resultados que mi consulta directa. Sigue sin mostrarme todos los registros.
Todos los registros de tratamientos los tiene un solo paciente, por lo que no puede haber errores, ya que si los busco directo por dni, salen...

Comment: El planteamiento del problema es claro y la respuesta no tanto. Te recomiendo que leas con atención para no confundir al compañero.

Comment: @gama984 la solución al error de SQL es esta, el problema reside es que no sabe que quiere exactamente

Comment: Ya encontré el error, el error es mi profesor que dijo que debían salir todos los tratamientos lo cual va en contra del problema ya que no todos los tratamientos llevan la palabra "dental". Tanto el código respuesta del compañero como el segundo aportado por mi son correctas.